Android WebView is loading the URL content in plain HTML when I override shouldInterceptRequest for posting data with OkHttpClient
I need to POST to a URL in a WebView with headers and a form body. I have added the below code but WebView loads the page content in plain HTML.
Can anyone please help me resolve this issue? Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
binding.webView.apply { 
settings.javaScriptEnabled = true 
settings.domStorageEnabled = true 
settings.allowContentAccess = true 
settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true 
settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true 
settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        
webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
           override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                showLoadingView()
                return false
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                hideLoadingView()
            }

            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest
            ): WebResourceResponse {
                return postDataOkHttpClient(supportCenter)
            }
        }
        loadUrl(supportCenter?.consumerUrl ?: "")
}

private fun postDataOkHttpClient(supportCenter: SupportCenter?): WebResourceResponse {    

    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val mediaType = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()

    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("token", supportCenter?.token ?: "")
    jsonObject.put("lang", supportCenter?.lang ?: "")
    jsonObject.put("channel", supportCenter?.channel ?: "")

    val body = jsonObject.toString().toRequestBody(mediaType)

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(supportCenter?.consumerUrl ?: "")
        .addHeader("Authorization", supportCenter?.authToken ?: "")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .post(body)
        .build()

    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

    return WebResourceResponse(
        getMimeType(supportCenter?.consumerUrl ?: ""),
        response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"),
        response.body!!.byteStream()
    )
}

private fun getMimeType(url: String?): String? { 
            var type: String? = null val 
            extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url) 
            if (extension != null) { 
            when (extension) { 
            "js" -> { 
                return "text/javascript" 
            }            
            "woff" -> {
                return "application/font-woff"
            }

            "woff2" -> {
                return "application/font-woff2"
            }

            "ttf" -> {
                return "application/x-font-ttf"
            }

            "eot" -> {
                return "application/vnd.ms-fontobject"
            }

            "svg" -> {
                return "image/svg+xml"
            }

            else -> type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
        }
    }
    return type
}

I have tried different settings for the WebView hence, you see so many settings applied, and set settings.layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL as well and I tried with and without mimeType in WebResourceResponse. But it doesn't seem to load the page properly.

Using OkHttpClient: You are using OkHttpClient to make a network request inside shouldInterceptRequest method. This approach is incorrect because shouldInterceptRequest is meant to intercept and modify the request, not to make new network requests. Instead, you should modify the original request passed as a parameter.
webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
    view: WebView?,
    request: WebResourceRequest?
): Boolean {
    showLoadingView()
    return false
}

override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    hideLoadingView()
}

override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
    view: WebView?,
    request: WebResourceRequest
): WebResourceResponse? {
    if (request.url.toString() == supportCenter?.consumerUrl) {
        val postData = "token=${supportCenter?.token}&lang=${supportCenter?.lang}&channel=${supportCenter?.channel}"
        val postDataBytes = postData.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)

        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
        headers["Authorization"] = supportCenter?.authToken ?: ""
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        // Execute the request asynchronously
        OkHttpClient().newCall(Request.Builder()
            .url(request.url.toString())
            .headers(Headers.of(headers))
            .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8"), postData))
            .build()
        ).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                // Handle failure if needed
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val contentType = response.header("Content-Type")
                val charset = response.body?.contentType()?.charset(Charsets.UTF_8) ?: Charsets.UTF_8
                val data = response.body?.string() ?: ""

                // Convert response data to input stream
                val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(data.toByteArray(charset))

                // Pass the response data to WebView
                view?.post {
                    view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, contentType, "UTF-8", null)
                }
            }
        })

        // Return null to indicate that the WebView should not load the original request
        return null
    }
    return null
}

}

Hi Qadir, thanks for answering the question. But this doesn't resolve the issue. Instead, it just displays the token=${supportCenter?.token}&lang=${supportCenter?.lang}&channel=${supportCenter?.channel} data as a string on the page.
Any idea how I can keep using the OkHttpClient and get the WebView to display the content properly?

Thanks for the update. Yeah, it loads the page now BUT the original issue is still there. It loads the page as plain HTML without any styling. :(

Can you post the screenshot of the code file structure of your Android studio. where are your html files and css files?

Its not a local HTML file, loading from a URL.

Thank you so much, Qadir, I did a little modification with your code and now it's working. Thanks again for your support for your support. I will answer in case someone else faces a similar issue.

A little modification to Qadir's answer above. It resolved the WebView issue while passing the media type as multipart/form.
Request.create() is deprecated and Headers as HasMap were not working. So, I added each header separately.
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest
            ): WebResourceResponse? {

                if (request.url.toString() == supportCenter?.consumerUrl) {
                    val mediaTypeText: MediaType = "text/plain".toMediaType()
                    val mediaTypeFormData: MediaType = "multipart/form-data".toMediaType()

                    val postData = "token=${supportCenter?.token}" +
                            "&lang=${supportCenter?.lang}" +
                            "&channel=${supportCenter?.channel}"

                    val body = postData.toRequestBody(mediaTypeFormData)

                    // Execute the request asynchronously
                    OkHttpClient().newCall(
                        Request.Builder()
                            .url(request.url.toString())
                            .addHeader("Authorization", supportCenter?.authToken ?: "")
                            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .post(body)
                            .build()
                    ).enqueue(object : Callback {
                        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            // Handle failure if needed
                        }

                        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                            val contentType = response.header("Content-Type")
                            val data = response.body?.string()?.trim() ?: ""

                            // Convert response data to input stream
                            // Pass the response data to WebView
                            view?.post {
                                view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, contentType, "UTF-8", null)
                            }
                        }
                    })

                    // Return null to indicate that the WebView should not load the original request
                    return null
                }
                return null
            }

